# Bezier Curve drawing issue on iPad Air

Tags: ios, bezier

I have following code which allows to draw curved line. User drawing straight line and once touch ended, control handles appear and user can modify line to desired curve.  It worked well on IOS 6 and IOS 7 on all iPads. But it works strange on iPad Air and iPad mini 2 which are running on IOS 8. When user pull handle to one direction, start point of line moves to opposite. So it's like reverse coordinates calculations.

```
-(void)drawStraightLine
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the line properties
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.5);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);

    // draw the line
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, d.x, d.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, c.x, c.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

-(void)showHandles
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, a.x, a.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, b.x, b.y);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, c.x, c.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, d.x, d.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, a.x, a.y);
    for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += EPSILON) {
        CGPoint p = [self bezier:t];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, p.x, p.y);
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.5);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    //[self showLines:ctx];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(a.x-5, a.y-5, 10, 10));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(b.x-5, b.y-5, 10, 10));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(c.x-5, c.y-5, 10, 10));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(d.x-5, d.y-5, 10, 10));

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Helvetica", 18.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0));

    NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%.0f,%.0f)", a.x, a.y];

    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%.0f,%.0f)", c.x, c.y];

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.width - 80, c.x - 10)), fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.height - 44, c.y + 10)), [label UTF8String], [label length]);

    //[NSString drawAtPoint:aPoint withAttributes:dictOfAttributes];

    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%.0f,%.0f)", d.x, d.y];
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.width - 80, d.x - 10)), fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.height - 44, d.y + 10)), [label UTF8String], [label length]);


    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%.0f,%.0f)", b.x, b.y];

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.width - 80, b.x - 10)), fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.height - 44, b.y + 10)), [label UTF8String], [label length]);

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.width - 80, a.x - 10)), fmax(30, fmin(self.bounds.size.height - 44, a.y + 10)), [label UTF8String], [label length]);
}
```

Comment: Would be worth showing your code for tracking the touch coordinates and some NSLogs from that code showing the difference in the coordinates between iOS7 and iOS8. In iOS8 screen bounds changed to be interface orientated rather than device orientated. If you use the screen bounds in your calculations that might be your issue.

Comment: This is good idea. Thanks! I'll try soon and Ii think that's the point!

Comment: Still trying fix it. When i move finger on Y axis, points start moving along X axis. And the same when  i move finger on X axis, points start moving along Y axis.